# error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, git

I am getting "`nothing to commit, working directory clean`" message on executing git status command

but when execute the git checkout branch-name produces an error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: wp-config.php
```

Please check the bellow git commands with the output:

---

```
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git update-index --assume-unchanged -- wp-config.php
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git diff .gitignore
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
index d9d785e..d180ece 100644
--- a/.gitignore
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -4,4 +4,3 @@ wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/
 wp-content/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/
 wp-content/plugins/jetpack/
 wp-content/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/
-wp-config.php
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git add .gitignore

shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git commit -F ../commitmsg.txt
[master d265e1a] Remove wp-config.php file from gitignore because with .gitignore, only untracked files are ignored.
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git push origin master
Password for 'https://user_name@bitbucket.org': 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 488 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 1 (delta 1)
To https://user_name@bitbucket.org/user_name/atoz-reviews.git
   c7bebee..d265e1a  master -> master
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git checkout develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    wp-config.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git stash save "Unknown changes with not file to commit"
No local changes to save
shahalom@microsolutionsbd ~/www/wp-projects/atoz-reviews $ git checkout develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    wp-config.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

---

I think it is related to `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- wp-config.php` command ... but what is the solution?

Comment: `wp-config.php` contains configuration values that are specific to each installation and sensitive information (database user and password). It **must not** be added to the version control system.

Comment: yes, you are right. Somehow I have added that file to git and now removed by using the git update-index command. Probably this is why I am getting the error...